# XML schema to list in C# or JS

Tags: c#, xml, list, xsd, schema

I am working on a "schema" search, where you can write some part of the xpath and after that, system should show you what are the further possibilities of the node (so what other node can be accessed after specific node). However, I am looking for some solution which would create me a list of possible parents and childs based on the schema.

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated of course because of wildcards, substitution groups, types derived by extension, model groups, and such details. I would recommend using an API offered by a schema processor rather that trying to analyse the source XSD documents directly. One approach, for example, would be to generate an SCM file from the schema using Saxon. You can then search the SCM file for all the declarations of a particular element name, look up their types, and from the types you can discover the list of allowed child element names. You would probably want to do this by first converting the SCM file to your own data structure geared to your particular needs: as you suggest, this might be a simple list of parent/child element name pairs (plus element/attribute name pairs, perhaps?).

Comment: Hi @Michael, yes exactly - it is quite complicated problem. Thank you very much for ideas. I will try to ask for the API, but most likely I will use SCM as you recommended.